# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, спп, придаточное-предложение, однородые

Предложение:

> Какая там обстановка и с какой порой года она больше соотносится,
>   напишем после.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Какая там обстановка и с каким временем года она  больше соотносится, напишем после.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с однородными изъяснительными придаточными, запятая при наличии одиночного союза И не ставится.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится: **Что это за соединение и кто такой Ковпак, мы тогда ещё не знали** (Медв.).

Иногда при перечислении однородных придаточных и **наличии паузы** можно поставить тире: **А что творилось в этом хаосе вещей, как он в нём разбирался — уму непостижимо.**

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142